# Get part of the list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say, I have a list and I want to get a portion of it.  Say I have 1000 data from 0 to 999.  Then I want to get from "index1" to "index2."

Sample data is :

```
[0] = 100
[1] = 1520
....
[900] = 8975
....
[998] = 10
[999] = 4875
```

Say for example I want to get values from index 900 to index 998. So the value return should be:

```
[0] = 8975
.....
[998] = 10
```

How to do that in LINQ?

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? have you heard of  `Skip()` and `Take()`? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `skip` and `take` for that

```
List<int> list= new List<int>;
list.Skip(900).Take(100);
```

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/213/using-c-linq---a-practical-overview/skip-and-take

Or, you can use the `GetRange` method

```
List<int> list= new List<int>;
list.GetRange(900, 100); // Retrieves 100 items starting with index #900
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_GetRange_System_Int32_System_Int32_